# Regex pattern matching java

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 java programs that does a pattern matching,

Program - 1

```
    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
            Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
            boolean b = false;
            while (b = m.find()){
                System.out.println(m.start());
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
    0
    1
    2
    34
    4
    5
    6
```

Program - 2

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Dog");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("This is a Dog and Dog name is Tommy");
        boolean b = false;
        while (b = m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.start());
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output-

```
    10
    Dog
    18
    Dog
```

Can someone explain how the regex works in both these cases.. Why in program-1 the matching is started from byte 0 and there on...whereas in program-2 the matching is matched on the whole string?

Answer (score 2):

`\\d*` means a **string containing *0 or more* numbers**.

You get results for *0 long* (empty) number strings...

You should probably try `\\d+` to find strings of numbers that are *at least 1 long*

#### Recommended reading

- [regular-expressions.info tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `*` in `\\d*` makes the digits optional.  That is, that pattern matches *every* byte.  It also specifically matches the digits when they are there, but it doesn't have to.

`Dog` is not an optional part of the pattern and is required for matching.